# How to access single values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe called actual:

[image]

I want to calculate the average value for the 2 columns "difference" and "difference_percentage". For this purpose I use the following code:

```
help_SumError_Absolute = 0
help_SumError_Percentage =0

for index in range (0, len (actual)):
    # First Try
    help_SumError_Absolute = help_SumError_Absolute +  actual.iloc [5, index]
    help_SumError_Percentage =help_SumError_Percentage + actual.iloc [6, index]
    # Second Try
    #help_SumError_Absolute = help_SumError_Absolute + actual ["difference", index]
    #help_SumError_Percentage =help_SumError_Percentage +  actual ["difference_percentage", index]
    
average_aboslute_error = help_SumError_Absolute / len (actual)
average_percentage_error = help_SumError_Percentage / len (actual)
```

So I just want to build the sum of all values in the columns and then divide it by the length of the array actual. Unfortunately, I get error messages. When using the code of the "First Try" with the iloc approach I get the following error message "IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds" and when using the code from the "Second Try" with a direct access approach I get the error message "KeyError: ('difference', 0)"

Can you tell me why those approaches do not work in this context? Basically I thought that the iloc approach is for integer based indexing?

I'd appreciate every comment.

Answer (score 0):

On the line that says:

```
for index in range (0, len (actual)):
```

you are using the length (first dimension/number of rows) of the dataframe as the upper-value for the range that you are looping through, ie. variable "index" will be 0, 1, .. actual.shape[0].

But when you index "actual" using "index" on the line that says:

```
help_SumError_Absolute = help_SumError_Absolute +  actual.iloc [5, index]
```

You do so along the second axis (columns), which has a different shape.

Hence you get an error saying that the index is "out-of-bounds" when index reaches a value greater than the number of columns in the dataframe (but not greater than the number of rows).

Try changing:

```
help_SumError_Absolute = help_SumError_Absolute +  actual.iloc [5, index]
```

to:

```
help_SumError_Absolute = help_SumError_Absolute +  actual.iloc [index, 5]
```

ie. swap the indices around.

Also, why don't you just do:

```
actual[["difference", "difference_percentage"]].mean(axis=0)
```

???

Comment: Thanks for your answer Vinzent. Now I use the following code: `for index in range (0, len (actual["difference"])):. 
    help_SumError_Absolute = help_SumError_Absolute +  actual.iloc [5, index]` but I still get the same error. I do not understand why because now I am reffering to the length of the columns `range (0, len (actual["difference"])`. And in the command ` actual.iloc [5, index]``  I use [5, index] as an arguement. Are arrays in pandas not accessed via [row, columns]? Why shall I swap the indices around? I do not undestand this.

Comment: You didn't change anything by doing that, the length of the column is also the length of the dataframe, ie. the number of rows. The problem (as I wrote in my answer) is that you are using the row-index to index the columns!. Why didn't you try what I suggested in the answer, ie change: `actual.iloc[5, index]` to `actual.iloc[index, 5]`.

Comment: Thanks Vinzent for your answer. Basically I just do not understand why I have to swap the index? Do you not access arrays in Python by using [column ,row, ]? Why is this vice versa in this case and I have to access the array by using [row, column ]? Further, I do not undestand why  `for index in range (0, len (actual["difference"]` does not give me the number of rows? I am asking for the length of the column with the label "difference" and the column with the name "difference" has about 2000 entries. So I would like to use them

Comment: And the reason why I do not use your suggested code `actual[["difference", "difference_percentage"]].mean(axis=0)` is that here I get a value of "inf" when using this as there are some 0 or near 0 entries. This is why i want to loop over the array/dataframe and exclude these values.

Comment: @PeterBe "Do you not access arrays in Python by using [column ,row, ]" No you do not, you access arrays in python using [row, column].. "Further, I do not undestand why for index in range (0, len (actual["difference"] does not give me the number of rows?" It does, that's what I have been saying all along, but you are using the row-index for the column, that's the problem..

Comment: @PeterBe ""And the reason why I do not use your suggested code actual[["difference", "difference_percentage"]].mean(axis=0) is that here I get a value of "inf" when using this as there are some 0 or near 0 entries." First of all 0-values should not cause problems when taking the average/mean.. "This is why i want to loop over the array/dataframe and exclude these values." There are much better ways to exclude values from a df than by looping through it.

Comment: Thanks Vinzent for your answer and effort. How do I access arrays in python when not using [column, row]? So it is vice versa? I have to access it with [row, columns] as in your suggested code?  You wrote " but you are using the row-index for the column, that's the problem.." I do not understand what you mean by that. Why am I using the row index? And how can I ask for the length of the column "differnces"?

Comment: You wrote "First of all 0-values should not cause problems when taking the average/mean.. " --> But it does cause problem when using your suggested code. It gives me the value inf. Further, you wrote "There are much better ways to exclude values from a df than by looping through it." --> What other approaches do you know that can deal with such values?

Comment: Thanks Vinzent for your answers. Any comments on my last 2 comments? I'd highly appreciate every further comment from you.